# BigQuery error 403 permission denied when i use "with" and "join" statements in query

Tags: python, google-bigquery, permissions

I'm working on a project with python3 and BigQuery and i encountered a strange behavior in google-cloud-bigquery library.
When i exec simple query like:

`select * from my.project where field1="foo" and field2="bar"`

The program running well but when I try to use a more "complex" query like:

`with a as (...),b as(...)`
`select * from a as a_el`
`select * from b as b_el`
`join b_el on a_el.field1 = b_el.field1 ...`

The program crash with:

`google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 request failed: the user does not have 'bigquery.readsession.create' permission`

So, I know this is a permission problem but my question is: what's the difference under the hood? Why extra permission are needed? The tables are in the same project, so where is the problem?

I use query() method for execute queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `google-cloud-bigquery` python library leverages the BigQuery Storage read api to download query results faster.  The permissions are part of the `roles/bigquery.user` predefined role.  Likely you've got a custom role on the project that excludes the readsession permissions, which are permissions specific to the BigQuery storage API.  This sounds like a case where the results from the first query are small enough that the storage API session doesn't get created.

More information about permissions can be found on the [access control](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control) page.

Comment: Thanks, very clear answer.